# how to copy and write a file from a specific line number

Tags: c

I would like to copy a huge txt file and 'shrink' it. this is my code, but it seems it's still takes a lot of time reading the file. is there a way to read from a specific line number to EOF? for instance, the first 1 million lines are not useful to me, how to read from line 1 million. or anyway to read from EOF?

```
include<stdio.h> 
include<stdlib.h>
void main() {
   FILE *fp1, *fp2;
   char ch;
   int i = 1;
   int n = 0;
   int k;

   fp1 = fopen("co.data", "r"); /*  open a file to read*/
   fp2 = fopen("Output.txt", "w");          /*  open a file to write*/
   printf("please enter how many lines do not need to be copied\n");
   scanf ("%d", &k); 
   while (1) {
      ch = fgetc(fp1);                        /*  a loop to read/copy    the file*/
      if (ch == '\n')                            /*  record the number of lines*/
      i++;   
      if (ch == EOF)
         break;

      else if (i>k)                       

         putc(ch, fp2);

   }

   printf("File copied Successfully!\n");
   printf("number of lines read is %d\n",i-1);
   printf("number of lines copied is %d\n",i-1-k);
   fclose(fp1);
   fclose(fp2);
}
```

Comment: `ch` should be an `int`.

Comment: You should read your file line by line using `fgets` instead of reading it char by char using `fgetc`. This is probably more efficient. But mch's comment is still valid.

Comment: As like `MichaelWalz` said, you should use fgets. `fgetc` read one character per iteration, but `fgets` read one line per iteration it will be much faster.

Comment: Do you know the length of each line?

Comment: If you want to get from byte 1 million, maybe there is some way depending on the file system. But for the getting from line 1 million, I think you must read the file to the memory line by line.

Comment: `execlp("tail", "tail", "-n", "+1000000", NULL);` – What I'm trying to say is to read the [source code of the `tail` program](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) for an inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

There are two potential answers to your question, depending on if your file has known line lengths or not.

---

> is there a way to read from a specific line number to EOF

In a file with **line lengths are completely arbitrary** (variable), no.

For example, if line 1 is 10 characters, and line 2 is 20 characters, then there is no way to calculate where line 3 is going to start without iterating through lines 1 and 2.

Operating systems aren't magic; if this kind of functionality was supported, they'd have to iterate through the file first as well. Either way, you're going to be looping through the contents.

---

Now, if the **line lengths are guaranteed to be the same**, that's a different story.

Say you have a text file like so:

```
AAAAAAA
BBBBBBB
CCCCCCC
```

Each line in the above text file is 7 characters. Assuming your line terminator is `\n`, each line takes up exactly 8 bytes.

In this case, you can safely `fread()` 8 bytes at a time and know that you're getting exactly one line. In order to jump to a particular *byte* in a file, you would use `fseek()`.

Since you know the length of the lines in this scenario, you could jump to line `N` by simply doing

```
fseek(fp1, S * N, SEEK_SET);
```

where `N` is the line number (starting at 0) and `S` is the length of the line (as mentioned above, 8 bytes in our example file).

---

Note that the second solution will break if you're using a multi-byte encoding such as Unicode. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Using **fgets()** i made program, try it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        FILE *fp1, *fp2;
        char ch,*str,*r;
        int i =0;
        int n = 0;
        int l;

        fp1 = fopen("co.data", "r");
        fp2 = fopen("Output.txt", "w+");
        printf("please enter how many lines do not need to be copied\n");
        scanf ("%d", &l);
        while (1)
        {
                if(r=fgets(str, 500, fp1))
                {                      /*  a loop to read/copy    the file*/
                        i++;
                }
                if (r == NULL)
                        break;
                else if (i > l)
                        fputs(str, fp2);

        }
        printf("File copied Successfully!\n");
        printf("number of lines read is %d\n",i-1);
        printf("number of lines copied is %d\n",i-1-l);
        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I get it when people say fgets is more efficient than fgetc. so, you cannot read a file from the mid of it in C? I thought it would not be available, but I am new to C, so Thanks anyway for answering this question.

Comment: @Dezhou Thanks in stackoveflow is Upvote and Accepting answer. Anyway happy coding.

Comment: @msc Please [turn on your compiler warnings](http://pastebin.com/raw/ZHTGSauV-)...also, you don't check those pointers and you don't check `scanf` for errors

Comment: `char *str;` and `fgets(str, 500, fp1)`?!?!  Just what memory does `str` point to?  And how do you handle lines greater in length than what you read in a single `fgets()`?

Comment: @Andrew Henle I took static memory, but we can take dynamic memory .

Comment: @msc - As currently coded, you're taking no memory.  `str` is an uninitialized pointer.